# Getting NullPointerException with return intent from startActivityForResult

Tags: java, android

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I've gone over it quite a few times...

I start an activity for result via:

```
Intent go = new Intent("android.intent.action.NEWTOURNAMENT");
            startActivityForResult(go,2);
```

Then, in the result activity, I have one button that when clicked calls the "Send()" method:

```
 public boolean checkValues(){
    allValuesCorrect=true;
    if(venue.getText().toString().equals("")){ allValuesCorrect = false;}
    if(buyin.getText().toString().equals(null)){ allValuesCorrect = false;}
    if(fee.getText().toString().equals(null)){ allValuesCorrect = false;}
    if(mm.getText().toString().equals(null)){ allValuesCorrect = false;}
    if(dd.getText().toString().equals(null)){ allValuesCorrect = false;}
    if(yyyy.getText().toString().equals(null)){ allValuesCorrect = false;}

    return allValuesCorrect;
    }

public void send(){

    if(checkValues()){
    Intent returnData = new Intent();
    returnData.putExtra("venueData", venue.getText().toString());
    returnData.putExtra("monthData", Integer.parseInt(mm.getText().toString()));
    returnData.putExtra("dayData", Integer.parseInt(dd.getText().toString()));
    returnData.putExtra("yearData", Integer.parseInt(yyyy.getText().toString()));
    returnData.putExtra("buyinData", Integer.parseInt(buyin.getText().toString()));
    returnData.putExtra("feeData", Integer.parseInt(fee.getText().toString()));
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnData);
    finish();
    }
```

So it won't send anything if any of these values are empty.

However, when I run this I get a force-close with an error logcat claims is caused by a null pointer exception on the first line of creating the new Tournament in the ArrayList Tournaments:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode==2){
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            tournaments.add(new Tournament(data.getStringExtra("venueData"), data.getIntExtra("monthData", 0),
                    data.getIntExtra("dayData", 0), data.getIntExtra("yearData", 0), data.getIntExtra("buyinData", 0),
                    data.getIntExtra("feeData", 0)));
            calculations();
        }

    }
```

So here's the logcat if it helps:

```
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.mustaroenterprise.APTTO/com.mustaroenterprise.APTTO.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3141)
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3184)
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at com.mustaroenterprise.APTTO.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:68)
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5192)
01-23 13:43:03.105: E/AndroidRuntime(941):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3137)
```

Comment: What is the line 68 of your MainActivity?

Comment: show your MainActivity code?

Comment: Line 68 of MainAcitivity is the one shown there as tournaments.add(new Tournaments(data.getStringExtra(.... etc

Comment: My guess is that `venueData` is null. If it was `monthData`, it would be set as `0` by default, so I guess it's not there the error. Before running the `.add(...)` sentence, try using `Log` over the `venueData` field and see whether it is null or not.

Comment: @NicolasMustaro is tournaments initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you initialized `tournaments.`

If it is initialized your `venueData` might be `null`.

Here is the reason,

```
if(venue.getText().toString().equals(""))
```

Here you are checking if the `String` is empty or not. You also need to check if it is `null` or not. If you know for sure it is not `null` there seems nothing wrong with your code.

Try that,

```
if(venue.getText().toString().equals("") || venue.getText() == null)
```